# How to config ParquetFileReader parallelism?

Tags: parquet, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to save partitioned spark sql dataframe(around 300 partitions) to hdfs and it's really slow:

> joined_table.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy(target).save(path_out)

I think this may be caused by:

> INFO ParquetFileReader: Initiating action with parallelism: 5

Any idea about how to config this parallelism? This link may be helpful: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1097/stall-on-loading-many-parquet-files-on-s3.html
but I have no idea how to use newAPIHadoopFile in Pyspark.